# Multiple substitutions in zsh?

Tags: scripting, zsh

I have a function that creates a new markdown file, but I was wondering how can I simplify this?

```
  today=$(date +"%F")
  title=$1:l
  clean_title=${title//[^a-zA-Z0-9]/-}
  filename="$today-$clean_title.markdown"
```

I figured I could combine the title/clean_title into one, but when I try something like `${1:l...` or `${$1:l...` I get console error about bad substitution. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nest the `${...}` bits, though do also consider how readable the code will be for future readers.

```
() { clean_title=${${1:l}//[^a-zA-Z0-9]/-}; printf "$clean_title" } " BLA "
```

Also the `A-Z` match probably doesn't make much sense given the earlier lowercase...

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, you can nest parameter expansion operators. You can also get the date with the prompt expansion of `%D{%F}` (`zsh` also has a `strftime` builtin in the `zsh/datetime` module if you want some more verbose and readable code).

```
filename=${(%):-%D{%F}}-${${1//[^[:alnum:]]/-}:l}
```